# Plotting x-axis and y-axis with different (indep) limits in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, time-series

I developed an Android app such that each scan is set to 1 Minute, and during this time the sensor collects many many readings randomly. I want to plot one sensor data of one scan only as follows:
The time of the scan is put manually in seconds for only 1 minute (from 1:60 sec) in the x-axis. While the vector of random readings collected from the sensor (sometimes reach hundreds of values) in the y-axis.

How I can do this in Matlab?

I tried using this code but gives me an error. "Vectors must be the same length."

This is my code:

```
x1 = linspace(0,60);
plot(x1,vector1,'o-r',x1,vector2,'+-k','LineWidth',lw,'MarkerSize',msz);
xlabel('Time (s)');
ylabel('sensor readings')
```

Comment: For each reading, do you have a corresponding time record? If so, you could create a time vector which has the same length as the `vector1`

Comment: I did the following, I collected readings every scan, and each scan is 1 minute of time (i.e., 60 seconds in x-axis). During each scan, the app collects a huge number of random readings (sometimes reaching hundreds), this should be the plot in the y-axis. I want to plot from (0~60 time(s) ) in x-axis. while the vector of the random length of collected readings in the y-axis. How I can do this.

Comment: As Banghua asked, do you know at what time point each reading is taken? If not, are the readings taken at fixed intervals? please [edit] your question to clarify it, don't add information in the comments.

Comment: I edited my question to be clarified.

Comment: Just `hold on` and plot 60 times (in a loop), once for each x axis value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to match the amount of values you have to modify the input for `linspace`:

```
x1 = linspace(0,60,length(vector1));
```

This way you will automatically get the right amount of entries for your x-axis vector.
You basically tell `linspace` to create a vector that ranges from `0` to `60` with `length(vector1)` entries, so that it matches the length of your data set.

Note that if your second data set has a different amount of entries as your first, you will need to create a different x-axis vector that respectively matches its amount of values.